# how to write equivalent raw request of form-data request in postman?

Tags: postman

I m using form-data - i pass 2 wav files via form-data. I'm using keys: "file1", "file2".

the flask app when using form-data:

```
def compare_voices():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file1 = request.files["file1"]
        file2 = request.files["file2"]
```

what postman form-data looks like:

[image: k]

I'm wondering how i can transform this in raw format in postman?
like

```
{
"file1" : "path to file1" , 
"file2": "path to file2"
}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get your point. What the image is showing is that your are actually sending the files (bytes) and the RAW data format you are describing is just a path to a file (no actual file sending happening)

Comment: @caravana_942, yes i just wanna know how to do same thing in raw request form - not in form-data  request.

Comment: But one question: Do you want to send the bytes or the path of the file?

Comment: @caravana_942, path, to be honest dont know, in form-data i send path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are trying to compare 2 WAV files. I think that at some point you will need the actual files and perform your computation.

You can write in that kind of format (It's called JSON) by clicking on raw and then specifying that your body is a JSON format.

[image]

Comment: thx but how to specify actual filepath? how to show file path?

Comment: By writing it in the value. Eg. { "path": "C:\User\Admin\Desktop\a.wav" }